# How show indicator for latitude and longitude by google maps having URL query?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the follow query in my html page:

< a href="https://maps.google.it:/?ll=41.373725,15.685977> Google Map < /a>

How show indicator like the follow ? which parameter should I use?
[image]

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with the Google Maps API v3?  It looks like it is just about Google Maps.  Or are you trying to use the "green arrow" icon for a marker on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map?

Comment: thaks for your warning, I modified the tag. 
I didn't try to use the "green arrow" icon for a marker on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map. How can I use it?